# Знаки вопроса в теме письма

Tags: c#, gmail

Программа на C#. System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient, отправляю письмо с кириллической темой (Subject). Сообщение System.Net.Mail.MailMessage. Firefox отображает нормально, у Gmail на Android тема "Результаты исследований" превращается в "Результаты исследо??аний". SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8. Как решить проблему?

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient( "smtp.mail.ru", 587 );
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential( "dubnikov@bk.ru", "password" );
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage( "dubnikov@bk.ru", "dubnikov@bk.ru", "Результаты исследований", "Тело письма" );
    message.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    client.Send( message );
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Если Вы добавите в вопрос весь код, который отвечает за формирование тела письма и его отправку, то Вам помогут гораздо быстрее.

Comment: оно https://stackoverflow.com/a/17696708/407561?

Comment: Вроде бы оно, но не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Решение такое (наверняка кому-нибудь пригодится):

message.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding( 1251 );